# How to stop the insert statement process fast in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have an insert statement that should insert 500k records, but after 2 hours, only 100k have been inserted.

I decided to cancel the process and now I can see that number of records inserted is going down very slowly.

Based on that it will take a day to undo those inserted rows.

Is there a way to stop that and accept whatever has been inserted or truncate that table easily and stop the "Cancelling Query" process?

```
insert into xT2 (a_i, b_i, a_icd, b_icd, a_code, b_code, a_spcode, b_spcode, a_forcode, b_forcode, distance)
    select
        a.i a_i,
        b.i b_i,
        a.icd a_icd,
        b.icd b_icd,
        a.code a_code,
        b.code b_code,
        a.spcode a_spcode,
        b.spcode b_spcode,
        a.forcode a_forcode,
        b.forcode b_forcode, -99 Distance
    from 
        xT1 A
    inner join 
        xT1 B on a.i < b.i
```

[image]

Comment: Cancelling a statement can be a *very* expensive operation, especially with an `INSERT` that has processed 100,000 rows already. The fact, however, that it's so slow sounds like that you have other operations that are effecting the insert; do you have some `TRIGGER`s or something on the table `xT2` or something? I would expect an `INSERT` that only contains 500,000 rows to be pretty quick. Or perhaps you don't have any indexes that help the RDBMS complete the `SELECT`?

Comment: how to force ending the cancellation and accept data as is?

Comment: That isn't how transactions work.

Comment: You can't accept it as is. That would violate the ACID property. If you cancel the insert it will have to rollback the entire transaction which can be time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to Sean Lange's comment above, you cannot accept a partial insert which has been inserted due to the A for Atomicity in the ACID properties.

Atomicity means that you guarantee that either all of the transaction succeeds or none of it does. You don’t get part of it succeeding and part of it not. If one part of the transaction fails, the whole transaction fails. With atomicity, it's either "all or nothing". I took this description from https://database.guide/what-is-acid-in-databases/ as it describes is concisely. If you have not done so already, read up on the other properties as they are very fundamental in understanding how a DBMS works.

As an aside, 500K rows is a relatively small amount of rows and should not take anywhere near 2 hours to insert, are there any NULLS in your a.i  column or is there a very heavy load on the system at the time the query is running? Just to add another possible item, is a.i indexed?